# add new word document in delphi

Tags: delphi, ms-word, delphi-xe

I am buliding a delphi form to add a new word document in MS Word and wait for the user to insert text and edit document, save the file and exit form MS Word, then get me the file name and path to the file.

```
 WordApp := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
 WordApp.Visible := True;
 Doc := WordApp.Documents.add();
```

wait for user insert text and edit document and save file and exit form MS Word THEN

```
Doc.Save;
DocName := Doc.Name;
Docpath := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(Doc.path) + DocName;

with ZipForge1 do
begin
  FileName := Zipfilename;
  OpenArchive;
  Options.StorePath := spNoPath;
  AddFiles(Docpath);
  CloseArchive;
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write your own event sink to listen to the Word application's `OnQuit` event. However, it's going to be easier to switch to early bound COM. The import type library, found in `Word2000.pas`, contains all that you need.

- Use `TWordApplication` for your application object.
- Assign your handler(s) to the events of the application object.
- Depending on precisely what you want to do, the events that seem most applicable are `OnDocumentBeforeClose` and `OnQuit`.

To illustrate, here's the most trivial example that I can devise:

```
uses
  Word2000;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  WordApp: TWordApplication;
begin
  WordApp := TWordApplication.Create(Self);
  WordApp.Visible := True;
  WordApp.Documents.Add(EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam, EmptyParam);
  WordApp.OnQuit := WordAppQuit;
  WordApp.OnDocumentBeforeClose := WordDocumentBeforeClose;
end;

procedure TForm1.WordAppQuit(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage('Word application quit');
end;

procedure TForm1.WordDocumentBeforeClose(ASender: TObject; 
  const Doc: WordDocument; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  ShowMessage(Doc.Name + ' closed');
end;
```